# How to open exteranal application on top of desktop using electron

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, desktop-application

I have page in my electron application where I display open application which I can recorder
[apps page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9paa.png)

These apps I get using DescktopCapturer.getSources() method and get there screen's ids and icons to display.

I want to show them on top of desktop after selecting one of them, for example I select Chrome and I need to open chrome using electron, how I can do this? thanks!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer on my question.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "${appName}"
   set frontmost to true
    windows where title contains "${name}"
    if result is not {} then perform action "AXRaise" of item 1 of result
end tell
```

If u dont't need to filter by title u can just do

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "${appName}"
       set frontmost to true
       perform action "AXRaise" of item 1 of result
  end tell
```